# EE: Show previous 3 blog entries prior to the current viewed entry

Tags: conditionals, ee

I have been stuck on this one for a few days now:

**Page Content:**

Main blog post (current entry) + a sidebar displaying the previous 3 blog entries

**Sidebar Code:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" status="open" limit="3" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic="off" url_title="not {last_segment}"}
                <!-- NEWS BOX # -->
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">

                    <img src="{blog_image}" class="project-img" />
                    <h4><strong><a href="{url_title_path='blog'}">{blog_title}</a></strong></h4>
                    {blog_description}

                </div>
                <!-- NEWS BOX # -->
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Goal:**

Regardless of the current blog being viewed, the sidebar should always display 3 previous entries posted prior to the 'viewed' blog entry date.

**As an example:**

- Blog 1 - *Entry Date: 2017-03-06*
- Blog 2 - *Entry Date: 2017-03-05*
- Blog 3 - *Entry Date: 2017-03-04*
- Blog 4 - *Entry Date: 2017-03-03*
- Blog 5 - *Entry Date: 2017-03-02*
- Blog 6 - *Entry Date: 2017-03-01*

If Blog 2 is the current entry in view, the sidebar would show Blog 3, Blog 4 and Blog 5

If Blog 3 is the current entry in view, the sidebar would show Blog 4, Blog 5 and Blog 6

If Blog 5 is the current entry in view, the sidebar would show Blog 6

**Any help** offered is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my guess would be you'll need an embed. the in the main template (within the channel:entries tag) call that embed something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
{embed="_inc/_previous_three_posts" the_start_date="{entry_date}" the_entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Your embed would look something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries start_on="{embed:the_start_date}" limit="3" entry_id="not {embed:the_entry_id}" dynamic="no"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Minor tweak to your suggestion to show the previous 3 entries, changed **start_on** to **stop_before** and added **orderby** and **sort**. Updated as follows:

`{exp:channel:entries stop_before="{embed:the_start_date}" limit="3" entry_id="not {embed:the_entry_id}" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic="no"}`